# Navigation bar on top of textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, navbar, nav

[image]

Anyone can help to clone it out? The "Name" part was actually a textarea, and on top of it was the Navigation bar when click on it will turn blue and underlined on the top of the textarea. 
i have the idea to create a navbar like this but not the same like this one.
Here was my code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a>Address</a></li>
    <li><a>Address Overview</a></li>
    <li><a>Identification</a></li>
    <li><a>Control</a></li>
    <li><a>Payment Transactions</a></li>
    <li><a>Status</a></li>
    <li><a>Additional Texts</a></li>
    <li><a>Technical ID</a></li>
</ul><br />
<div class="row form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" style="min-width:100%"></textarea>
</div>
```

and it came up like this
[image]

Comment: You need to style it in CSS, for instance for the textarea you can remove border and padding to get it closer to the top image you provided.

Comment: then how about the when Click on the Address, it will underlined instead of highlight the nav box in grey? Css too?

Comment: Yes, you can add an active state on click and hover. You can check out https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Can you just show me how you going to make it like my second image? I had tried to remove the textarea padding top, but still didn't stick it like the first image